# plpgsql: calling a function with 2 OUT parameters

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to fetch to values from a plpgsql function with 2 OUT paramenters but I have some problem.

These are the functions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_test(OUT x text, OUT y text)
AS $$
BEGIN
   x := 1;
   y := 2;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
----------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_test_read()
RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
   xx text;
   yy text;
BEGIN

   SELECT get_test() INTO xx, yy;
   
   RAISE INFO 'x: <%>', xx;
   RAISE INFO 'y: <%>', yy;

END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

The output of the command:

> select get_test_read();
>
> INFO:  x: <(1,2)
>
> INFO:  y: <>
>
> get_test_read
>
> ---

So both the values go to the first parameter.
I cannot find some example on how to call a function like this.

Comment: Just use "select * from get_test_read();" to get named columns.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As you have 2 `OUT` params, your function will return a [record](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW).

In order to get all values you should use function as the source of your data and put it into the `FROM` clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM get_test() INTO xx, yy;
```

Comment: it gives me error as follows:
 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "into"

Comment: @Muhammed - You can only use `SELECT... INTO...` inside a function (with such named variables defined). the answer does not clearly indicate that. If you are doing this outside a function just omit the `INTO...` part.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * INTO xx, yy FROM get_test();
```

**UPDATE:**

Explanation:

Modifying the second function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_test_read()
RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
   xx text;
   yy text;
BEGIN

   SELECT * INTO xx, yy FROM get_test();
   
   RAISE INFO 'x: <%>', xx;
   RAISE INFO 'y: <%>', yy;

END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is similar to SELECT INTO with TABLE, where only get 2 values:

```
SELECT "FIELD1", "FIELD2" INTO variable1, variable2 FROM "TABLE" WHERE ...
```

[Npgsql Basic Usage](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html?q=stored%20procedure)

[PL/pgSQL Function Parameter Modes: IN, OUT, INOUT](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-function-parameters/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Could you give a bit of explanation? It would help OP and future readers :)

Comment: OK xShirase, I have modified my answer with an explanation