# Using OUT parameters in Postgres Stored Procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Is there any way I can set some value to OUT parameter in Postgres stored procedure? Below is the example what I want to do. In oracle PL/SQL you can use out parameters and set it to any value and return it. After that u can use that value and manipulate it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION demo_procedure(p_invoice text, OUT p_out1 integer, OUT p_out2 integer)
  returns SETOF record
as
$func$
DECLARE
   s_inv_rest integer;
   s_state integer;
BEGIN

      BEGIN
      SELECT "REST_TO_PAY", "STATE" 
      INTO s_inv_rest, s_state
      FROM "INVOICE"
      WHERE "INVOICE_REFERENCE" = p_invoice;
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       p_out1 := 1;
       p_out2 := 2;
       RETURN;
     END;

END;
$func$
language plpgsql;
```

So in this example for instance if no data is found I want to return some out code and out message.

Comment: Something like this? IF FOUND THEN _do_something ELSE _do_something_else END IF. Details can be found in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS

Comment: Looks like you already have done it.
Will this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584002/plpgsql-calling-a-function-with-2-out-parameters
give you an idea?